# Is the degree of a differential equation of any use?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

> When it is written as a polynomial equation in the unknown function and its derivatives, **its degree of the differential equation** is, depending on the context, the polynomial degree in the highest derivative of the unknown function, or its total degree in the unknown function and its derivatives.
>
> -[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation)

Now this definition means that one is allowed to manipulate the given DE to a polynomial form to determine the degree. This is what is also taught in most schools.

However, this allows many absurd manipulations and contradicting answers. For example, consider

$$y'=x\;\;\;\;,\;\;\; y'^3=x^3$$

Both equations are equivalent and satisfy the polynomial definition, but have different degrees.

This led to many claiming$^{\dagger}$ that the degree must be determined in the purest, given form, with no form of simplification, which goes against the original definition of possible polynomial manipulation.

Some answers on this site tell me that most modern texts do not talk about the degree at all$^{\dagger\dagger}$. This makes me think that degree is just a useless concept that offers no insight into the solution of the DE itself, at the same time being so ill-defined, unlike the order which offers information on the number of constants.

Is my conclusion right, or, is there actually any valuable insight that the degree provides?

---

$^{\dagger}$

- [Order and degree of a differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4034214/734160)
- [Differential equation degree doubt](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1117694/1040658)
- [How to find degree of a differential equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2436288/1040658)

$^{\dagger\dagger}$

- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2446912/734160

Comment: Equations $y' = x$ and $y'^3 = x^3$ while having the same solutions are different equations, with different degrees. So degree is not invariant under equivalent transformations, but it's not necessary a problem by itself. However I don't think there is anything special for equations of given degree, except the case of degree 1 (linear equation).

Comment: I’d say don’t worry too much about this term. I think it could be avoided entirely without too much rephrasing.

Comment: The equations have the same solutions over the reals, for example, but not over the complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

$$\large{^{\dagger}}$$
I think the information about the degree of the DE is useful, e.g.:
Per se, the two expressions ($y' = x \Leftrightarrow \left( y' \right)^{3} = x^{3}$) are equivalent, but they do not have all the solutions in common:
$$
\begin{align*}
y' = x &\implies {\color{Blue}{y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + \text{cosntant}}}\\
\left( y' \right)^{3} = x^{3} &\implies {\color{Blue}{y = \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^{2} + \text{cosntant}}} \wedge {\color{Red}{y = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3} \cdot i}{4} \cdot x^{2} + \text{cosntant}}}\\
\end{align*}
$$
since [$\left( \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3} \cdot i}{2} \cdot x \right)^{3} = x^{3}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28-1-sqrt%283%29i%29%2F2x%29%5E3) but $\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3} \cdot i}{4} \cdot x \ne x$.
This isn't a big deal with these ODEs, as it's extremely simple, but as complexity grows, assuming they're the same can lose a lot of solutions.

But to be fair, I believe that with $^{\dagger}$ in application contexts these lost solutions don't really mean anything usefull, at least I can't think of any that do.

---

$$\large{^{\dagger\dagger}}$$

Furthermore, the degree information also gives a good indication of the difficulty of solving the DE. As the degree increases, so does the degree of difficulty of solving it (most of the time). E.g.: [$y'''' + y = \ln\left( x \right)$ is still solveable with special functions but quite difficult](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=DSolve%5By%5Bx%5D%20%2B%20y%27%27%27%27%5Bx%5D%20%3D%20Log%5Bx%5D%2C%20y%5Bx%5D%2C%20x%5D). If we raise the degree now for some reason e.g. $\left( y'''' \right)^{4} + y = \ln\left( x \right)$, then we may as well give up.

I would even go further and say that the specification of the degree is very important because it is also the basis for the functionality of many solution methods. E.g. some substitutions aimed at depressing the DE to their characteristic equation or just to find for the homogeneous solution (like $y = e^{\lambda \cdot x}$ in $f\left( x \right) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\left[ a_{k} \cdot y^{\left( k \right)} \right] \wedge n \in \mathbb{N}$ were all $a_{k}$ are constants).

But, I don't read about the degree of differential equations very often either. When I see it, they often only differentiate between degree $1$, other intiger degrees ($\in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \left\{ 
0,\, 1 \right\}$) and non-initger degrees ($\not\in \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: You make a very fair point.

Answer (score 2):

For most DE the idea of a degree will appear superfluous, either because most of the DE you encounter are explicit, have degree one in the leading derivative, or are non-polynomial in the other terms.

On the other hand, if the degree makes sense it is mostly so obvious that you rarely notice it. Take for instance $y'^2+y^2=1$, one of the equations for a harmonic functions. It is readily visible that this has two solutions for $|y|<1$, $y'=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$.

Many textbook examples of implicit DE are also polynomial or algebraic, mostly Clairaut and related equations. While the degree describes how many solutions may cross in each point of the domain, it is secondary to the solution process. The solution is usually obtained by considering the system of the DE and its derivative, see [How to solve tougher Clairaut's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414963/how-to-solve-tougher-clairauts-equation), [Is there any systematic way for transforming differential equation into Clairaut form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2829369/is-there-any-systematic-way-for-transforming-differential-equation-into-clairaut).

This works for all implicit equations, the derivative is explicit, the multiplicity comes from extending the initial state to one derivative more by using the original implicit equation.

Comment: Could you explain this "While the degree describes how many solutions may cross in each point of the domain, it is secondary to the solution process. "

Comment: If you can describe an implicit DE as polynomial in the highest-order derivative, then at each point of the domain in time-state space you have up to "degree" solutions for this highest derivative. Some of them may be complex and thus disregarded for real solutions. Continuity in the highest derivative allows to select the "correct" root via local uniqueness of the implicitly defined function, except at points with multiplicity. // The enumeration of solutions in the Clairaut case is via the constant slope of the linear solution family, that these solutions cross is secondary.

Answer (score -2):

The degree of a differential equation (after reduction to its simplest, lowest-possible exponent in any derivative) is very informative, for instance by indicating the maximum number of eigenvalues or solution classes.  This degree also states what kinds of solution techniques will likely work when solving the equation.  Moreover, it will tell the number of free parameters that are needed to specify an initial condition that leads to a unique solution.

Comment: What you describe is the order of the DE. For an example with degree greater one take a Clairaut equation $y=xy'+y'^2$.